# Exe is not valid win32 application but running on 64bit

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012

I have the application that I was modifying and then I compiled it in `Visual Studio 2012` (`C++` app). When I tried it on `64bit windows`, application worked, but when I´m trying to run it under `32bit windows xp` I´m getting message like "`.exe` is not a valid `win32` application". I have found several advices on the internet but nothing worked so now I don´t know where is the problem because I´ve been testing it on several `win7 64bit OS`.

In `Visual Studio` in Configuration manager window I have selected option `win32` at project´s platform column.

Comment: Sure sounds like VS is still compiling to 64-bit :(

Comment: Did you recompile it for 32-bit or are you trying to run the same EXE file that you built on the 64-bit system?

Comment: VS2012 by default no longer supports building executables for XP.  You'll need at least Update 1 and change the Toolset setting to v110_xp.

Comment: Hans Passant: Thank you. I have downloaded update 4 and set up toolset and it worked. I didnt know that VS2012 do not supports XP build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should review all the project settings.

"Win32" is just a name. For e.g., you can target Machine->X64 in linker setting despite the configuration name.

Comment: I had target machine set to X86 but it seems I needed update for VS2012 to compile for XP.

Comment: Yes... to make your app runnable in XP you have to download the service pack (obviously the latest is the recommended) and change the general properties to use it (named v110_xp)

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, I would say you are linking against 64-bit only libraries which are not available on the 32-bit platform. Check your linker settings and build again.